# React Native: how do you include constructor with functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Up until now in React Native, I've always created components like this

```
class <name> extends Component {
  constructor(props) {...}
  componentDidMount() {...}
  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

I see that in newer documentation they create components like this:

```
function <name> {
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

If I'm using the second syntax, how do I add `constructor` and `componentDidMount`?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on react's documentation for react hook, you can make use of the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) hook and pass in an empty array as the dependency array,

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
>   unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
>   tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
>   or state, so it never needs to re-run.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // insert logic for componentDidMount here
}, []);
```